# Casting a ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection to a ListBox.ObjectCollection?

Tags: c#, collections, casting, listboxitems

Is it possible to cast a ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection to a ListBox.ObjectCollection in C#? If so, how would I go about it?

Comment: I've got two identical methods, except that one of them accepts all items in a listbox ("Add all printers"), and another which adds only selected items ("Add selected printers"). I want to do it with overloading, but rather than looping through to put the values in an array I wanted to know if I can cast them both to something.

Answer (score 11):

I have a function that accepts `List<string>`.

I can pass both SelectedItems and Items by casting them.

Try this:

```
SelectedItems.Cast<string>().ToList()
Items.Cast<string>().ToList()
```

`<string>` could be replaced with some other object type.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible.

Instead, you should use an `IList`.
Both of these types implement `IList`, so you can pass either one as an `IList` without any explicit casting.

If you really wanted to, you could create a new `ListBox.ObjectCollection` and add the items from the `SelectedObjectCollection`.

Comment: what about @341184 answer ?

Comment: @Kiquenet: He's _copying_, not casting.  Also, he isn't using `ObjectCollection`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer: it is working for me.

```
System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection lst  =this.lstImage.SelectedItems;
List<string> selectedItems = new List<string>();

foreach (object obj in lst)
{
    selectedItems.Add(obj.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  List<YourDataType> YourDataTypeList = new List<YourDataType>();
  for (int i = 0; i < lbVectors.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
   {
        YourDataType v = lbVectors.SelectedItems[i] as YourDataType;
        YourDataTypeList .Add(v);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer I used to convert Checked list box to list box

```
CheckedListBox.CheckedItemCollection s= checkedListBox1.CheckedItems;

        List<object> ns = new List<object>();

        foreach (object ob in s)
        {
            ns.Add(ob);
        }

        listBox1.Items.AddRange(ns.ToArray());
```