# Cannot convert SelectedObjectCollection to ObjectCollection ?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I am trying to get a list of all elements from ListBox if no or one of items is selected or list of selected items if more than 1 are selected. I have written such a code but it doesn't compile :

```
    ListBox.ObjectCollection listBoXElemetsCollection;

    //loading of all/selected XMLs to the XPathDocList
    if (listBoxXmlFilesReference.SelectedIndices.Count < 2)
    {
        listBoXElemetsCollection = new ListBox.ObjectCollection(listBoxXmlFilesReference);
    }
    else
    {
        listBoXElemetsCollection = new ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection(listBoxXmlFilesReference);
    }
```

So for this piece of code to work I would need to use something like `ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection listBoxSelectedElementsCollection;` which I do not want because I would like to use it in such an `foreach`:

```
            foreach (string fileName in listBoXElemetsCollection)
            {
            //...
            }
```

Comment: this is [one good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4074736/661933) i found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd simply this a bit and not mess with the ListBox ObjectCollections if you don't need to.  Since you want to iterate items on your ListBox as strings, why not use a List and load the list how you show:

```
List<string> listItems;

if (listBoxXmlFilesReference.SelectedIndices.Count < 2) {
    listItems = listBoxXmlFilesReference.Items.Cast<string>().ToList();
} else {
    listItems = listBoxXmlFilesReference.SelectedItems.Cast<string>().ToList();
}

foreach (string filename in listItems) {
    // ..
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert `SelectedObjectCollection` to an array of `object[]`.

```
ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection sel = new 
                     ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection(listBoxXmlFilesReference);
ListBox.ObjectCollection col = new 
                     ListBox.ObjectCollection(listBoxXmlFilesReference,
                         sel.OfType<object>().ToArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

I can see what you're trying to do and it doesnt compile because the type `ListBox.ObjectCollection` is not the same as `ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection` - even though  in your case they are lists that contain strings the classes themselves are different hence the compile error.

Assuming your items are strings in the listbox you could do:

```
var items = listBoXElemetsCollection.Items.OfType<string>();
if (listBoXElemetsCollection .SelectedIndices.Count >= 2)
      items = listBoXElemetsCollection.SelectedItems.OfType<string>();      

foreach(var item in items)
            //do stuff
```