# Pulling multiple value members from list box

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a list box which the user can select multiple lines from, this list box basically contains a list of pets the user has, each pet has a reference, the pets name is displayed and each of the items value member is the reference of that pet. If the user has selected multiple pets within the list box, I would like to pull each of the value members so I can process them, so far this is the code I have:

```
        string lvCat;
        foreach (Object selectedCat in lstCustCats.SelectedItems)
        {
            lvCat = selectedCat as String;
            DataRow Cats = dSSystem.Bookings_Cats.NewRow();
            Cats["BookRef"] = lblBookingRefR.Text;
            Cats["CatRef"] = lvCat;
            dSSystem.Bookings_Cats.Rows.Add(Cats);
            this.bookings_CatsTableAdapter.Update(this.dSSystem.Bookings_Cats);
        }
```

This code fetches the first item within the list box for each selected item, but does not iterate through the list box, any idea on how I can accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and checking to make sure `lstCustCats.SelectedItems` actually contains the selected items?

Comment: this code should iterate over all selected ListBoxItems, can´t see any  failure! How does the foreach behave? Exit after fetching the first object of SelectedItems? Maybe you have just selected one?

Comment: Please explain your last sentence in more detail.  What first item?  If it gets anything "for each selected item", how is it _not iterating through the list_?

Comment: @sine Well it goes through fine, up until when it's supposed to assign the value member to the lvCat variable, instead it's assigning 'null' to the variable, even though the value member property is entered.

Comment: @DonBoitnott It was originally only selecting the first reference from the first selected item and using the same reference for all records added after.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange I have just checked it now and it is correctly showing all selected items.

Comment: Perhaps you should loop over `SelectedIndices` instead and reference what you want more directly.  Personally, I find the somewhat anonymous nature of the items collection to be a bit odd to work with.

Comment: You said `selectedCat as String` assigns `null` to `lvCat`, which means the type conversion to `string` fails. Are you sure all the items in the list are of type `string`? Because in your loop header you treat them as objects, but in the body you treat them as strings regardless.

Comment: I think PoweredByOrange is right ;-)

Comment: @PoweredByOrange Looking at this, lvCat is being given the value of "{System.Data.DataRowView}", is this to do with the binding? Which would fail to convert to a string obviously.

Comment: @MoonPunch Well binding is a very broad term, but you can do something like `lvlCat = (selectedCat as DataRowView).Row[index];` where `index` is the column index you're trying to get the value from.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to do `lvCat = selectedCat as String;` which is wrong, because the items in `lstCustCats.SelectedItems` aren't strings.
this should work

```
lvCat = selectedCat.ToString();
```

i'm flaging it as duplicated but it's damn close to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074706/casting-a-listbox-selectedobjectcollection-to-a-listbox-objectcollection).
after you'll run that code, if you got in the lvCat a class name, then that's the class `selectedCat` is type of. in that case you can cast `selectedCat` to that type and continue from there

Comment: If `selectedCat` is a custom type, running a `ToString()` on it will return the object type (assuming the object doesn't override this method), which is useless in this case. He needs to cast the object to whatever type it is and then access a property/method on it.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange if it is a custom type then at least he'll know which type. i'll add it to the answer